# How to convert float to string in Ocaml and store in a variable

Tags: floating-point, ocaml

All I want to do is store a float as a string to a variable, I used following code:

```
let float_number = 0.00005 in
let str_number = string_of_float float_number in
Printf.printf "%s" str_number;;
```

After running this code i got "5e-05", it's not what i wanted, i want the exactly "0.00005". I know `Printf.printf "%f" float_number` prints out "0.00005" but it's not stored in a variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Printf.sprintf to accomplish this. To keep the string exactly the same as the literal float I had to add the precision format directive `.5` to the format string.

```
# let float_number = 0.00005
let str_number = Printf.sprintf "%.5f" float_number ;;
  val float_number : float = 5e-05
val str_number : string = "0.00005"
```